# Flask page load error jquery .load

Tags: jquery, flask, jinja2

I am having trouble pulling in a page from a content directory I am getting a 404 error but the path is correct I am using Flask and jinja2 templates

The content pages are supposed to be displayed on the stream when a menu button is clicked

127.0.0.1 - - [01/Dec/2015 21:44:02] "GET /dashboard/content/home.html HTTP/1.1" 404 -

[image: current file structure]

```
    #views.py
    #templates/dashboard/content/home.html
    @dashboard.route('/content/home')
    @login_required
    def home():
        return render_template('/content/home.html')
```

The jquery works fine on its own

```
     /*Div Content change on menu click*/
     $(document).ready(function(){
     //Initial page load
     $( ".stream-content" ).load( "/content/home.html");
     //handle menu click
     $("ul.stream-nav li a").click(function(){
     var page = $(this).attr("href");
     $(".stream-content").load("./content/" + page + ".html", function(){
      });
     return false;
       }); 
     });
```

The menu url is this
          Home
when clicked I get this path where is the bold section pulled in from?
         127.0.0.1:5000**/dashboard/content/**/dashboard/content/home.html

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find the answer I used this with a standard block so its a template within a template within a template base loads steam and steam loads home 
        {% if not standalone %}{% extends 'content/stream.html' %}{% endif -%}